# How to classify images using the pixel differences?

Tags: image-processing

I have two gray scale images of covered and uncovered mouth. i have to classify which image is covered and uncovered using pixel differences. i do not want to go in machine learning like classify using local binary pattern and then train the images using SVM or neural network. Is there any appropriate method to do it?
Below is the image of covered and uncovered mouth.
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLR47.jpg)

Comment: Come on - I think you need to make a bit more effort! If you only have those two images the answer is that the top one is covered. Have you got more samples? Are the mouths always covered by fingers or are you suddenly going to spring a $10 note on us covering a mouth once we have a solution for fingers? Are they always black and white only - why no colour? Are the mouths sometimes only a small percentage of the picture? What if there are 2 mouths? What OS and tools can you use? What have you tried?

Comment: Basically i am doing my masters thesis on driver drowsiness. so when driver is drowsy it may open mouth or covered mouth with fingers which is spontaneous action of human being. yes it is always in gray scale for image processing. I am using MATLAB for it. i have only detect face and then extract these regions from face.

Comment: So every time I eat something in my car your will think I am tired? Tracking the eye movements seems more appropriate to me.
I don't think simple pixel difference will work here. What about beards, lipstick, singing operas :D